# SQL JOIN query for linking four tables together

Tags: sql, join

Display a list of employees names,salaries,and the name of the city in which they work for IT developers who do not earn a comission who work in the operations department in Italy

I did this

```
SELECT e.first_name,e.last_name,e.salary,l.city
FROM employees e join jobs j
ON(j.job_id = e.job_id)
WHERE AND e.commission_pct = 0 AND 
job_title LIKE '%IT Developer%'

join locations l 
ON (l.location_id = d.location_id)
AND (l.country LIKE '%Italy%'
AND department_name = 'Operations');
```

Comment: ...and then what happens next in the story?

Comment: kindly clarify your question and requirement so we can help you out.

Comment: Please write a query with a minimal test. Add DBMS you are using

Comment: how do I add pictures on this to show the diagram I am using

Comment: @JoeTaras    http://imgur.com/lex2SyV   this is my Logical ERD and I am using PHPMYAdmin

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking if why the Query is not working? Your Join Syntax is not correct. It should be something like below:

```
SELECT  e.first_name
    ,   e.last_name
    ,   e.salary
    ,   l.city
FROM    employees e join jobs j      ON (j.job_id = e.job_id)
                    join locations l ON (l.location_id = d.location_id)
WHERE e.commission_pct = 0
AND job_title LIKE '%IT Developer%'
AND (l.country LIKE '%Italy%'
AND department_name = 'Operations');
```

Comment: http://imgur.com/lex2SyV     this is the link for the logical ERD and I tried the sql query you posted it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
SELECT 
    e.first_name,
    e.last_name,
    e.salary,
    l.city
FROM employees e join jobs j
ON(j.job_id = e.job_id)
JOIN locations l 
    ON (l.location_id = d.location_id)
    AND (l.country LIKE '%Italy%'
    AND department_name = 'Operations')
WHERE e.commission_pct = 0 
AND job_title LIKE '%IT Developer%'
```

Comment: http://imgur.com/lex2SyV      this is the link for the logical ERD for the question .I checjed the sql it doesn't work